# Only accept naked domain request, not subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I can't seem to explain Apache to accept requests on the naked domain but to ignore anything coming from a subdomain. I have the feeling this should be easy but everything I find is related to redirecting subdomain requests, not ignoring them.

My current setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example
</VirtualHost>
```

Accessing `something.example.com` directs to `example.com`, I would like it to fail with a `404 not found`. I can probably exclude everything with `mode_rewrite` but is that the best solution? Or should I do this on the DNS level?

Thank you for helping me out with such a n00b question.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a second virtual host to act as a catch-all and just return 404s. More or less like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  a.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
  RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
</VirtualHost>
```

- If a request arrives on `*:80` and asks for `example.com` it gets handled by the first virtual host.
- If a request arrives on `*:80` and asks for `*.example.com` it gets handled by the second virtual host.

Comment: Thanks but... using this and accessing `something.example.com` still ends up in the 1st virtual host, not the second. Is there a possibility Apache thinks the naked domain is the wildcard one?

Comment: You do have the NameVirtualHost directive, right?

Comment: Yes and no. I did not add it as it's already specified in the `ports.conf` file (installed Apache 2 via the Debian package). That should be fine, no?

Answer (score 1):

Based on mauro.stettler's answer I found something that works:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/example
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName *.example.com
   ServerAlias *.example.com
   Options -Indexes
</VirtualHost>
```

It throws a `403 Forbidden` instead of a `404 Not found` but that will do.

Without the `-Indexes` part it shows the directory structure of my `/var/www` directory. Would that be the default Apache uses as a fallback?

Comment: ServerName  doesn't take wildcards so what's actually happening is the ServerAlias is matching everything bar example.com. You might try taking the ServerName *.example.com out of the second vhost. If that fails use something like a.example.com with a wildcard ServerAlias.

Answer (score 0):

First virutal host is a default one and will  match every request for unknow VH

Do something like this:

```
# First VH
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName loalhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/default
</VirtualHost>

# Second and more VH
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example
</VirtualHost>
```